# Debugging Video Frame Differences

Tags: javascript, video, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm trying to decode an h264-encoded video frame using a decoder that has fairly limited capabilities ([Broadway JS](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway)).

Here's the process I'm using for testing:

1. Encode single image using h264 (output is ~62KB) using OpenH264 from Cisco, write to disk
2. Read file as binary in JS (loaded via XHR)
3. Decode in JS using Broadway
4. Display in canvas

I actually have a functional example of this, but there's a manual step at the moment between steps 1 and 2 - I have to call FFMPEG to force a small translation, and I can't figure out why.

I have successfully integrated Cisco's Openh264 library into my project, and can encode the image as h264 and write it to disk. I've confirmed the encoding itself is valid by using FFMPEG to extract the frame back out as a JPEG (looks perfect).

But, to make the frame decode properly in JS, I have to do a conversion using FFMPEG. It does some magic, the file size drops to ~58KB, and voila, everything starts working.

The Openh264 libraries only work with the baseline configuration, so I'm assuming I have some other random parameter set incorrectly. Problem is, if I use ffprobe to compare the frames - the settings are identical! But the file sizes are different, so obviously *something* is different.

So now the final question - what tool can I use to truly see what FFMPEG is doing behind the scenes here to make my "manually" encoded frame work? Is there a tool that will let me compare *all* the details of two h264 frames?

Answer (score 0):

Broadway is based on Android's Stagefright decoder. You should extract it from there, and run your file through this C based decoder. It'll be much easier to debug.

From my own testing, Broadway always fails to decode non-multiple of 16 pixels row & column files. Also, it supports a very limited format for the stream, so you might need to "strip" -copy stream in FFMPEG terms- them.

Typically, I had an issue getting long SPS and PPS NAL decoded correctly with broadway, generating fake SPS/PPS worked. Some encoders enable all the bell and whistle for their Sequence Parameter Set, while they only use the basic. So not advertizing features that are not used is actually a way to get more compatibility.